# Strapi Rest API - Nextjs - Server error: Fetch Failed

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

I use Strapi and Nextjs. When trying to fetch Data threw the Rest api i´m getting the Error (see Screenshot)
The Rest API is working and the URL for the fetch is correct as well...

Operating System: Mac OS
Strapi: 4.5.3
Node: 18.12.1
Next: 13.0.6

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday and it drove me crazy. I finally fixed it by reverting to older versions of Strapi and Node. Try this:

- Install a version manager tool like asdf or nvm
- In your project directory, set Node version to v16.19.0
- Re-install Strapi using `npx create-strapi-app@4.3.8 my-project --quickstart` in the terminal (Strapi version 4.3.8)

This solved my issue. Hopefully it works for you too. This Strapi page has some version info that also might be helpful. I used it to determine what versions to revert to:
https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/quick-start.html#_1-install-strapi-and-create-a-new-project